# Fetch type of property from a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing something in which I need to get the type of property on a given Type:

```
type FooBarType {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
}
```

The function would look like this: `getType<K extends keyof T>(key: K): string`, and such the output of calling the function with `foo` as the parameter would be `string`:

```
getType<FooBarType>('foo' as as keyof FooBarType) // string
```

I do not have an implementation of the generic at this point, so using indexed access types seems out?

Is this possible?

So far I have this:

```
getType <K extends keyof T>(key: K): string {
    type property = T[keyof T]
    // not sure how to continue here as I can't use T as a value
}
```

MWE:

```
type Config {
    database_host: string,
    database_pass: string | undefined,
}

const defaultConfig: Config = {
    database_host: 'host',
    database_pass: undefined
}

const config = ConfigBuilder<Config>.resolve(defaultConfig, new EnvironmentVars(), new YamlFiles(['../path/to/yaml']))

class ConfigBuilder<T> {

   public resolve(...): T {
     // from default: key: string
     const configKey: keyof ConfigType = key as keyof ConfigType
     if (foundValues.hasOwnProperty(key.toUpperCase())) {
            config[configKey] = this.parse(configKey, foundValues[key]) 
     }
   }

   private parse<K extends keyof ConfigType>(key: K, value: any): ConfigType[K] {
        const type = this.getConfigKeyType(key)

        if (this.parserDictionary[type]) {
            return this.parserDictionary[type].parse(value)
        }

        throw Error(`Could not find parser for type ${type}`)
    }

    private getConfigKeyType<K extends keyof ConfigType>(key: K): string {
        type configItems = ConfigType[keyof ConfigType]

    }

}

// config {
//     database_host: 'host',
//     database_pass: 'pass'    
// }
```

*Either, or none* of the env. vars or the parsed files can provide the `database_pass` value.

Comment: `FooBarType['foo']` will already return `string` for example.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic how do I programatically access that?

Comment: Since Typescript types are erased during compilation usually there is no possibility to get this information during runtime (unless you use reflection with more metadata) if the types you are interested aren't the general JS types. I wonder why you want to query the types during runtime in the first place? Usually this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic I'm building an object based on environmental variables, in which everything obviously comes in as a string, having the ability to type things naturally makes things easier. I have a default config, which might have some undefined things, and leaving to the environment to add configs in later, but I want to avoid having a large config file which lists both process and default as well as other input devices.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE on what you'd like to use this `getType` method for in particular? Specifically showing how you want to use the return value of this method since I think you want to do something that is not reasonable.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic not exactly working, but I used `typeof defaultConfig[key]` before.. which was great until I got not yet defined property values. I've updated the question above

Comment: In your new snippet I don't see where and how you'd like to use your `getType` method. That's crucial to grasp why you think you need it in the first place.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic apologies, must have accidentally removed it whilst I editing something. Updated, see the `parse  function`

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comment you can already do it with `FooBarType['foo']`.

If you want it programatically, with typings:

```js
interface FooBarType {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

const obj: FooBarType = {
   foo: '',
   bar: 1
}

function getValue<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
   return obj[key];
}

getValue(obj, 'foo'); // return string value
getValue(obj, 'bar'); // return number value
```

Comment: I don't think that the OP wants to access the actual value but wants the stringified type, so `getValue(obj, 'foo') === 'string'` etc., basically metaprogramming/reflection during runtime.